# Смещение ударения на последнюю букву, сопровождаемое её заменой

Tags: орфоэпия

В русском языке прослеживается тенденция к смещению ударения в некоторых существительных на последнюю букву с одновременной заменой этой буквы ("ы" или "и") на другую букву ("а" или "я"). Некоторые слова со смещённым на последнюю  заменённую букву ударением уже стали литературной нормой (дирЕкторы - директорА, трАкторы - тракторА, гОды - годА, бАржи - баржИ, склАды - складЫ и т.д.), некоторые сейчас имеют статус разговорных или просторечных (бухгалтерА, тортА, тренерА, договорА и даже слесарЯ и кабелЯ). Можно ли как-то объяснить эту тенденцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А. ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ СПРАВКА

1)  Для сущ. м.р. после твердых основ возможны ДВА ВИДА ОКОНЧАНИЙ в форме Р.п. мн.ч:  (ОСНОВНОЕ безударное окончании Ы и ВАРИАНТНОЕ ударное окончание А), если ударение в начальной форме падает на предпоследний слог: трактор – тракторы и трактора, редактор – редакторы и редактора.

2) Нормы произношения МОГУТ МЕНЯТЬСЯ. В настоящий момент существительные с суффиксом ОР/ЁР/ЕР делятся на три части:

а) только вариантное окончание А (слова этой группы рекомендуется запомнить): профессорА, директорА, докторА, шулерА б)  только основное окончание Ы: ректоры, лекторы, бухгалтеры, диспетчеры, снайперы, редукторы, центнеры; в) допускаются оба варианта: инспекторы и инспекторА, теноры и тенорА, джемперы и джемперА, свитеры и свитерА (окончание Ы относится к нейтральному стилю, а окончание А – к разговорному стилю).

Примечание

А) Форма профЕссоры соответствует старой норме, а также встречается у поэтов.

Б) Согласно словарям только форма директорА является нормативной, хотя  ещё в начале 20 века  говорили дирЕкторы; однако сейчас  форма дирЕкторы  начинает  вновь активно использоваться.

3) Окончания могут различаться не только по стилю, но и по  ПО СМЫСЛУ: 
лагери (политические)  и лагеря (для отдыха), учители (духовные) и учителя (в школе), образа (церк.) и образы (в литературе и искусстве), хлебы (печеные) и хлеба (злаки), счёты (инструмент) и  счета (денежные), роды (грамматические) и рода (войск).

Б.  ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС

Таким образом,  дело не в ударении, а в самом окончании.  В общем случае вариантное окончание А  имеет сниженную лексику (разговорную или профессиональную), так как в этом случае НА ПИСЬМЕ не различаются   две формы существительного (начальная форма и форма мн. числа Р.п.), которые В УСТНОЙ РЕЧИ различаются ударением, например: современные тракторА и нет трАктора.

К сожалению, грамматические особенности окончаний не изучаются в школе, поэтому у пользователей не складывается изначально культура их употребления.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, Vera!